# Glassfish 3.1.2 reload needed jars after application deployment

Tags: deployment, netbeans, jar, glassfish, ejb

I have an ebj using some external libraries (in this case, those libraries are written by myself). I have included them in my EJB.

The problem is that glassfish seems to load the needed jars only once (at first deployment) and consider he already has the jars for further deployment. It's only an assumption but if i do any changes in one of the library used by the EJB, redeploy the EJB, the changes made will not be applied... Glassfish still use the old jars he might keep in cache or something like that (i can find any mark of the jars in the the glassfish repositories).

The only solution i have found so far is restarting the server... not really suitable for development/test session where you have to wait for glassfish to restart every little change you make.

My question is: Is there a way to avoid this behavior and force glassfish to reload needed jars at each deployment?

Thanks for reading me.

Note: I'm working on local using netbeans to deploy but doing it straight from the glassfish admin console lead to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem with Glassfish 3.1.2 on the Windows platform.  When the application is being deleted or redeployed from my IDE, something has those files open and (apparently) Windows wont' let the deploy operation remove them.

My solution was to change the deployment to a "full deploy" using the "Real Jar Archives for Deployment" on each publish, instead of the more dynamic and faster "directory deployment".

I don't know what/how to make this change for Netbeans, as I no longer use Netbeans.

For Eclipse: Double-click on your server on the `Servers` view/tab to open the server's `Overview` settings.  Bottom-most setting on the page is `User (sic) Real Jar Archives for Deployment ...`.  Check it (not checked by default), and try again.

Comment: I'll try to see how i can get this behavior with netbeans. It's apparently tagged as bug by oracle and one solution i read was to add the ejb into an enterprise application. It works unless you add netbeans plugin dependency to your EJB and that's what i do. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if someone else is doing the same but i have to add netbeans plugins to my EJB dependencies. It works perfectly but when i'm trying to do the tricks i have mentioned on my previous comment with the enterprise app. it leads to this error: "Target "dist-ear" does not exist in the project <ejb_name> at the EE application compilation. I'm currently trying to see why.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i have finally got some concrete results. I don't know if there is lot of people working the way i do but i will expose the solution i have found to fit my needs.

First, if you are deploying EJB on standalone java client using netbeans platform (so using netbeans plugins) you may feel concerned.

The problem was that glassfish (3.1.2, i don't know if the same issue happen with others releases) do not reload needed jars when you redeploy the EJB. So, if your EJB has some dependencies and if some changes are made in them, glassfish will not see them and will keep using the old jars even after the EJB (re)deployment. It's tagged as bug by oracle so i think it will be solved quite soon (or not) but until oracle do his job, here is a solution.

Note: This error is only happening when your EJB has netbeans plugin dependencies. If it's not your case, you can just add your EJB into an enterprise application and deploy it and yours jar will be automatically reloaded.

Assuming your are in my case. If you compile your EE app containing your EJB that depends of a netbeans plugin. You may got this error:

```
Target "dist-ear" does not exist in the project "the path your netbeans plugin"
```

To solve this, i have added the target to the *build-impl.xml* file of the plugin.

```
<target name="dist-ear" />
```

Then add the netbeans plugin as dependency of the enterprise application.

After redeploying the application, your EJB's dependencies may have been loaded and you don't need to restart your glassfish server.